# Reload Jquery UI Parent Dialog

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog

All,

When I click a link on a web page, a JQuery UI Dialog opens up and it loads some ajax content into it. If I click a link inside this dialog, it opens up a child dialog. When I click "OK" in the child dialog, I want the child dialog to close and refresh the ajax content in the parent dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you already have the code that closes the child dialog ? Is it an alert() call ? If so, simply add a

```
        location.reload();
```

after the alert call. If it's something more complicated like a link, try

```
$('a.link-that-closes-dialog').click(function(){
  //Code to close the dialog
  location.reload();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this script for choose if show/hide any content.
After clicking button "Ritira" in the dialog, the page redirect me in the same page but whit a querystring (ex. www.mypage.ext?t=yes).
The script work, but I wish at the click of the button "Check Out" there is a refresh of the page.
I tried to enter the location.reload but did not work:

```
        $(function() {
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".dialog-ritira").dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: true
            });
          });

          $(".ritira").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");

            $(".dialog-ritira").dialog({
              buttons : {
                "Ritira" : function() {
                  window.location.href = targetUrl;
                  location.reload();
                },
                "Annulla" : function() {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                }
              }
            });

            $(".dialog-ritira").dialog("open");
          });
        });
```

Thanks