# Reload parent dialog content when child dialog is closed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have a large jQuery dialog window that opens up many more dialog windows inside when buttons are clicked in the parent dialog window for updating the database.

I want to update the parent window when the child dialogs are closed.

I can see how to do this with event close and `load(url)` but how do I make the association between child and parent without specifying each and every ID.

Comment: Is this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2296231/227646) helpful?

Comment: @kush I think this reloads the whole page and not just the dialog content. If this shouldn't happen where should I be calling the location.reload()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some markup structures, I cannot understand how your child dialogs resides inside parent.

jQuery has a function called [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) that travel up the DOM tree to find the nearest matching selector, so you can use this by giving a class to the parent dialog. And select them, when you want to use it like.

```
$(this).closest(".parent").html("Updated Content");
// ^ Represent your child dialog as you want
```